# Cocoa draw image with rounded corners and shadow

Tags: cocoa, core-graphics, shadow, clip

I am trying to draw an image using core graphics such that it has rounded corners and a drop shadow.  Here is a snippet of my code:

```
CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0, 1), 2, shadowColor);    
CGContextAddPath(context, path);
CGContextClip(context);
CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, image);
```

The problem I am having is that the clipping to create the rounded corners is also clipping the shadow.  Since the image may be transparent in areas, I cannot simply draw the rounded rectangle with a shadow under the image.  I guess I need to apply the rounded shape to the image first, and then draw the resulting image to the screen and add the shadow.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

Okay, so assuming that you have a UIView subclass, which has an instance variable, image, which is a UIImage, then you can do your drawRect: function like so...

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    [super drawRect:rect];

    CGRect _bounds = [self bounds];
    CGColorRef aColor;
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // Create a path
    CGRect insetRect = CGRectInset(_bounds, kBSImageButtonBorder, kBSImageButtonBorder);
    CGRect offsetRect = insetRect; offsetRect.origin = CGPointZero;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(insetRect.size);
    CGContextRef imgContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGPathRef clippingPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:offsetRect cornerRadius:CORNER_RADIUS].CGPath; 
    CGContextAddPath(imgContext, clippingPath);
    CGContextClip(imgContext);  
    // Draw the image
    [image drawInRect:offsetRect];
    // Get the image
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    // Setup the shadow
    aColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.0f green:0.0f blue:0.0f alpha:0.5f].CGColor;
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor(context, CGSizeMake(0.0f, 2.0f), 2.0f, aColor);     

    // Draw the clipped image in the context
    [img drawInRect:insetRect];

}
```

I'm a little new to Quartz programming myself, but that should give you your image, centered in the rectangle, minus a border, with a corner radius, and a 2.f point shadow 2.f points below it. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a function to round the corners of an image using Daniel Thorpe's answer, in case you came here, like me, just looking for a way to do this.

```
+ (UIImage *) roundCornersOfImage:(UIImage *)image toRadius:(float)radius {

    // create image sized context
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(image.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // add rounded rect clipping path to context using radius
    CGRect imageBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    CGPathRef clippingPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:imageBounds cornerRadius:radius].CGPath;
    CGContextAddPath(context, clippingPath);
    CGContextClip(context);

    // draw the image
    [image drawInRect:imageBounds];

    // get the image
    UIImage *outImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return outImage;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an imageView with a layer, the layer has properties for setting shadows and borders, this is how:

```
    self.imageView = [[NSImageView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0,0,60,60)];
    self.imageView.image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"yourImageName"];
    self.imageView.wantsLayer = YES;
    self.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10;
    //make the shadow and set it
    NSShadow* shadow = [[NSShadow alloc] init];
    shadow.shadowBlurRadius = 2;
    shadow.shadowOffset = NSMakeSize(2, -2);
    shadow.shadowColor = [NSColor blackColor];
    self.imageView.shadow = shadow;
```

Hope this helps, this is also much faster to draw then using drawRect overrides